# Using textbox with no button , Enter to execute then Only numbers allowed

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, keydown, enter

when i execute it will run but when i press the enter key the message box still appears

for  moneytextbox Keydown

```
         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
         {
            int a, b, c;
            a = int.Parse(money.Text);
            b = int.Parse(bill.Text);
            c = a - b;

            change.Text = c.ToString();
        }
```

for moneytextboxKeypress

```
 if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)))
 {
      MessageBox.Show("please enter digits only");
      e.Handled = true;
 }
```

i tried to unblock the enter key in the keypress event

```
if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter))) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("please enter digits only"); e.Handled = true; 
}
```

but "message box" still appears

Comment: i tried to unblock the enter key in the keypress event                                       
                                                                                                                   
     if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter digits only");
            e.Handled = true;
        }                                                                                                                  messagebox still appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling Keypress twice since once you press anything on your keyboard, the keydown event will triggered. Since you press the "keypress", both the keydown and keypress event handler will be triggered. Put everything on keydown event handler to handle all your request:

```
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            int a, b, c;
            a = int.Parse(label1.Text);
            b = int.Parse(label2.Text);
            c = a - b;

            label3.Text = c.ToString();
            return;
        }

        if (!(Char.IsDigit((char)e.KeyData) || (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter digits only");
        }
```

And remove the moneytextboxKeypress.

Comment: when i press a letters the messagebox appears but the letter appears on the textbox ,, your code is a big help tho , thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help @PrinceJkc.